# Select particular dates from nsdictionary

Tags: iphone

I have an `NSDictionary` which looks like.

```
dic is : {
city = #;
country = #;
date = "2011-08-12 05:00:00 +0000";
"day_of_week" = Fri;
high = 79;
icon = "/ig/images/weather/chance_of_storm.gif";
low = 61;
startdate = "2011-08-12 05:00:00 +0000";
state = #;
}


dic is : {
city = #;
country = #;
date = "2011-08-13 05:00:00 +0000";
"day_of_week" = Fri;
high = 79;
icon = "/ig/images/weather/chance_of_storm.gif";
low = 61;
startdate = "2011-08-12 05:00:00 +0000";
state = #;
```

}

```
dic is : {
city = #;
country = #;
date = "2011-08-14 05:00:00 +0000";
"day_of_week" = Sat;
high = 79;
low = 58;
startdate = "2011-08-12 05:00:00 +0000";
state = #;
```

}

```
if(( [dd1 earlierDate:startDate]) &&[dd1 earlierDate:endDate] ) 

                {     
                    /*if([dd1 isEqualToDate:startDate] || [dd1 isEqualToDate:endDate] )
```

I am passing `NSDate`s from test cases. Startdate and enddate are passed from the test cases and dd1 is passed from the parser which is the date. I am trying to get values between 2 dates but getting all 4 dates. What is the solution to get only the date values I wish?

DD1 IS NSDATE OBJECT AND I AM GETTING IT FROM NSDICTIONARY.SO DD1 IS RUNNING INSIDE A FORLOOP WHERE I AM GETTING DATES AS 201-08-12,2011-08-13 ETC

Comment: Did this not help you at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032347/get-date-from-an-nsdictionary-and-match-them

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare a `NSDictionary` to an `NSDate`. This is how you would extract the dates and calculate the difference:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss zz"];
NSDate *startDate = [formatter dateFromString:[dd1 objectForKey:@"startdate"]];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:[dd1 objectForKey:@"date"]];
NSTimeInterval intervalInSeconds = [startDate timeIntervalSinceDate:date];
[formatter release];
```

Not 100% sure about the last part of the `dateFormate` string, but it should work.

Comment: NSDateFormatter is completely unnecessary as NSDate provides all the comparison methods needed here.

Comment: @glorifiedHacker Cool. How do you get the NSDate from an NSString?

Comment: @Mundi You get an NSDate from an NSString using an NSDateFormatter - but unless I misunderstood the question, that is not what the OP is asking here. If he were sending an "earlierDate:" message to an NSDictionary object, then he wouldn't be getting any dates, as his app would crash. Since he is complaining of getting too many dates, and not complaining of his code crashing, I assume that dd1 is an NSDate object.

Answer (score 0):

From the bit of code that you did post, it's not apparent what 4 dates you are talking about. However, your if statement doesn't make sense as you are trying to apply boolean logic to objects (earlierDate: returns a pointer to an NSDate object). Try something like this:

```
if(([dd1 compare:startDate] == NSOrderedDescending) && ([dd1 compare:endDate] == NSOrderedAscending))
```

This should only evaluate to true if the date that dd1 represents is between startDate and endDate.

Comment: my nsdictionry looks like somethingdic is : {
    city = #;
    country = #;
    date = "2011-08-12 05:00:00 +0000";
    "day_of_week" = Fri;
    high = 79;
    icon = "/ig/images/weather/chance_of_storm.gif";
    low = 61;
    startdate = "2011-08-12 05:00:00 +0000";
    state = #;
} 
dic is : {
    city = #;
    country = #;
    date = "2011-08-13 05:00:00 +0000";
    "day_of_week" = Sat;
    high = 79;
    low = 58;
    startdate = "2011-08-12 05:00:00 +0000";
    state = #;
}

Comment: Please don't post that kind of stuff in the comments - it's virtually unreadable in that format. Edit your question and append that information in a well-formatted manner.

Comment: I see that you edited your post to include the extra dictionary information. Did you try out the if statement that I posted above though? If it isn't working for you, then you need to explain in more detail what the problem is.

Comment: WELL IT RETURNED ME NO DATES.

Comment: I would suggest taking a second look at those dates and making sure that the output you are expecting is reasonable given the input.

Comment: my dates that I am trying to do has been passed fine.What the issue is I have to pass numerous test cases.(10 in number).I have to get the weather of the dates between the dates I wish to pass.